# Client Reconnection

Tags: signalr

My understanding of the (JavaScript) hub client is that if a connection is lost, it enters a 'Reconnecting...' phase which attempts to reconnect. If it can't do so, it will enter a 'Disconnected' state which is where it'll stay until asked to start again.

<strike>How long is the 'Reconnecting...' phase meant to last before it gives up? I've read 40 seconds before, but my client seems to take much less time - about 10, maybe less.</strike> [*EDIT: Nevermind this part, I had configured a 10 disconnect on the server as a test... and forgot. I understand this is set by the server during the negotiate. Makes sense!*] ...  I'd prefer to have the client continually retry until it is told to abort - can this be done, and would it cause issues?

Another question; during the Reconnecting... phase, if I attempt to call a hub method (again, in JS) it never seems to complete. I'm using the returned Deferred to check for 'done' and 'fail' events, but neither seems to get called. Is this by design?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely have it continually reconnect.

Handle the disconnected event on the client and call connection.start:

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       $.connection.hub.start();
   }, 5000); // Re-start connection after 5 seconds
});
```

The only issues this would cause is that you could potentially be triggering infinite requests to a server that isn't there for client machines.  This becomes even more troublesome when you introduce the mobile market into the situation (drains battery like crazy).

When you attempt to call a hub method while reconnecting SignalR will try to send your command.  Since there are 2 channels, one for receiving data and one for sending, (for all transports except web sockets) in some cases it can still be possible to send requests while your offline.  Therefore SignalR does not know if a request fails until the browser tells it that it could not successfully make the request.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The first fix is an awesome way to introduce memory leaks.

Comment: @davidfowl The javascript to reconnect on disconnect? How on earth would that cause a memory leak?

Comment: @FireLizzard Look at the history of the post http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15125363/revisions

Comment: Remember to re-join any Groups on the client side that you had already joined.

Answer (score 0):

I might have a clue... Touching the Web.config produces an appPool Recycle, meaning that a new worker process will be created for new requests while the existing process will continue for a while until the remaining requests end or the timeout is reached. Request that do not end in the timeout period are terminated.

Signalr client reconnects to the new process while the long running task is running in the old process, so when on the long running task you do

`GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ForceHub>();`

you actually get a reference for "old" hub while the client is connected to the "new" hub.
That's why the test preformed by Wasp worked: he was making a new request to publish on the signalr hub that was processed in the newly created worker process.

You could try to configure a singalr backplane (https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr), it’s really easy to configure it using Sql Server (https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-sql-server). The backplane should be capable of connect the two worker processes and hopefully you will get the notification on the client.

If this is the problem, notifications generated by new requests will work even without the backplane. Notice that the real purpose of the backplane is to scale out signalr, this is, to connect a farm of WebServers between them.

Also keep in mind that running long-running task inside IIS is as task hard to achieve as, among other things, IIS does regular appPool recycles and has timeout limits for the requests to execute. I recommend that you read the following post: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx 
“If you think you can just write a background task yourself, it's likely you'll get it wrong. I'm not impugning your skills, I'm just saying it's subtle. Plus, why should you have to?”

Hope this helps